# NLP Categorizing Details with Confidence Values

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, categories

### Background

I'm writing a Swift application that requires the classification of user events by `categories`. These categories can be things like:

- `Athletics`
- `Cinema`
- `Food`
- `Work`

However, I have a **set list** of these categories, and do not wish to make any more than the minimal amount I believe is needed to be able to classify any type of event.

### Question

Is there a machine learning (nlp) procedure that does the following?

1. Takes a block of text (in my case, a description of an event).
2. Creates a "percentage match" to each possible classification.

For instance, suppose the description of an event is as follows:

> Fun, energetic bike ride for people of all ages.

The algorithm in which this description would be passed in would return an object that looks something like this:

```
{
    athletics: 0.8,
    cinema: 0.1,
    food: 0.06,
    work: 0.04
}
```

where the values of each key in the object is a **confidence**.

If anyone can guide me in the right direction (or even send some general resources or solutions specific to iOS dev), I'd be super appreciative!

Comment: Could someone explain why this is being downvoted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about typical classification model. I believe iOS offers you APIs to do this inside your app. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml) Look for natural language processing bit - [NLP](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/naturallanguage/nlmodel)

Also you are probably being downvoted because this forum typically looks to solve specific programming queries and not generic ones (this is an assumption and there could be another reason for downvotes.)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I suppose it's not a popular question because of it's specific nature.